# Does using the TOP X * format in SQL speed up queries significantly?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

So lately when I run queries on huge tables I'll use the the `top 10 *` notation like so:

```
select  top 10 * from BI_Sessions (nolock)
where SessionSID like 'b6d%'
and CreateDate between '03-15-2012' AND '05-18-2012'
```

I thought that it let's it run faster, but it doesn't seem so , this one took 4 minutes(or is that OK time)?

I guess I'm curious about whether the `top` functionality happens after it pulls all the data anyway(which would seem like it's inefficient).

thanks

Comment: i dont htink that will help... did you make sure your CreateDate column is indexed?

Comment: @Randy - That's a good point. I'm still not so familiar with indexing, and also my company's database. I will find out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It entirely depends on the query, with the exceptino of "Top 0".  "Top 0" does return much faster.

In your case, the query has to look through the rows in a huge table to find rows that match the WHERE clause.  If no rows are found, the number of rows being returned doesn't help.  If the rows are at the end of the table scan, then the number of rows being returned doesn't help.

There are certain cases with more complicated queries where the "top" could affect performance.  There is a difference between optimizing overall and for the first row returned.  I'm not sure if SQL Server's optimizer recognizes this difference.

Comment: Thanks so much Gordon! I will need to study some more to understand some of these issues, thanks!

Comment: SQL Server can indeed optimise for first row, at least `EXISTS` doesn't even return any data, never mind processing multiple rows.

Comment: EXISTS and SELECT * go together well, as the SQL engine will return as soon as it has found a valid row.

Comment: I believe the optimiser does recognise top N as it does ORDER BY when there is a range involved. It will look for a useful index and even suggest one (in management studio). If you run the query often enough, it will create an index in the back ground. However even small changes in the query statement layout can invalidate this process. It you have manually created and named the query, the optimiser will just look at the stats to see how much it thinks the index will help speed the execution. Indexes need stats to be up to date to maximise their effectiveness.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends. If you do not have a covering index on BI_sessions and its a large database then the answer is probably. A good covering index may be something like: CreateDate, SessionSIS, and all the columns you actually need to return. If you do have a coveing index, then SQL will not even read the table, it will get all the data it needs from the covering index. Possibly if you specified the columns you actually need to return, 10 rows should come back in a fraction of a second.
 for more useful info
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1078/improve-sql-server-performance-with-covering-index-enhancements/ 
and a bit more technical:
http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/
also 
http://www.sqlserverinternals.com/
and
http://www.insidesqlserver.com/thebooks.html

Comment: Thanks so much Ian! I'll need to look up  covering "index "

Comment: But wouldn't it use the index regardless of whether the query contains "top"?

Comment: The problem is not "top". The SQL engine needs to do a table scan, it does not have enough to get to the relevant rows via an non existant index. The best index is: which is the "finer" choice, i.e. which limits the number of rows most without the top N. This should in general be the first named column in the complex index, other columns in less limiting order. If there are only nine records satisfying the where critera, without a suitable index the SQL must check ALL rows to see if can find a 10th valid. If it has a good index it can get the top rows it needs. It knows there isnt a 10th.